# Quarto compilation failing after updating to version 1.2.269

Tags: texlive

I'm using quarto in RStudio (windows) to compile a markdown document to pdf with xelatex. Until now I was using the quarto 1.1... version, all was working fine. Today I have updated to version 1.2.269 and I can compile my document no more, the xelatex call hangs in a 'tlmgr updating' call. It generates .tex output but RStudio never ends. However my TexLive installation is updated, as I have checked manually with tlmgr. Launching xelatex from TexWorks works ok and xelatex can compile this .tex file and generate the correct pdf file. Any advice about what can be wrong with quarto or texlive after this update? Thanks in advance

Comment: As manually compiling works fine, maybe better suited for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quarto

Comment: Thanks for the indication, will post there.